# How to update a Step Function in AWS CLI without Deleting the Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have been working with AWS for the last month and ***I need to know how can we update the step function without changing the name of the file***.  
The way that the documentation provided to make the changes in the step function is to change the name of the existing one and add the changes in the file. But that will eliminate the logs that have been created in the AWS CLI.

For Example, if I replace the following code with something else I have to change the whole dynamic of the project in order to make them appear in the AWS CLI
[image]

Can somebody please provide a solution for this??

Comment: what is your actual update?

Comment: I need a general answer for this. I need to keep the execution logs and stuff on the CLI after updating. 
The only way that Doc provides is to change the name and replace the entire thing. 
Can you recommend a way to make a difference in this case?

Comment: Could you attach your bash commands for deployment to this post?

Comment: @chehsunliu yes of course. I found a way to do this. I'll post an Answer down there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update part can be done through an AWS configuration command. Follow the commands below, it will keep all the changes in the execution logs as wells.

```
let aws = require('aws-sdk');

let roleArn = `roleARN goes here`;

let params = {
  name: stepFunctionName,
  roleArn: roleArn,
  definition: JSON.stringify(definitionGoesHere),
};

let stepFunctions = new aws.StepFunctions();

stepfunctions.createStateMachine(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("error occured while creating the step function");
    console.log(err, err.stack);
    if (err.code === "StateMachineAlreadyExists" && err.statusCode === 400) {
      let paramsUpdate = {
        stateMachineArn: "stateMachine ARN for the existing stateMachine",
        definition: JSON.stringify(definition),
        loggingConfiguration: {
          includeExecutionData: true,
        },
        roleArn: roleArn,
      };

      stepfunctions.updateStateMachine(
        paramsUpdate,
        function (error, updateData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("error occured while updating the step function.");
            console.log("Error", error.stack);
          }
          console.log("step function updated successfully");
          console.log("response", updateData);
        }
      );
    }

    console.log(
      "step function does not exist and the function creation and update faild in the process."
    );
    console.log("definition", definition for the stateMachine);
  } // an error occurred
  else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```